# Why does a ifconfig command results in "Network is unreachable" on Android?

Tags: networking, shell

First, the sole purpose of the following steps is reproducing a problem in a way as simple as possible.
An Android device has an Ethernet port, and is connected to a router (IP: 192.168.1.1) via an Ethernet cable. A device on the network has IP: 192.168.1.163

Initially, shell command "ifconfig eth0" produces the following:

```
eth0: ip 169.254.0.125 mask 0.0.0.0 flags [up broadcast running multicast]
```

Shell command "ping 192.168.1.163" generates the following:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.163: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.00 ms
```

After running shell command "ifconfig eth0 ip 192.168.1.166 netmask 255.255.255.0", shell command "ifconfig eth0" generates the following:

```
eth0: ip 192.168.1.166 mask 255.255.255.0 flags [up broadcast running multicast]
```

Shell command "ping 192.168.1.163" generates the following:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.163: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.18 ms
```

Everything is as expected so far.  The following step will start the problem. After using shell command "ifconfig eth0 ip 169.254.0.125 netmask 0.0.0.0" to restore the initial settings, "ifconfig eth0" generates the following:

```
eth0: ip 169.254.0.125 mask 0.0.0.0 flags [up broadcast running multicast]
```

Please note it looks **exactly the same** as the initial settings. However "poing 192.168.1.163" generates the following:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

if Android Settings is used to do the configuration as shown by the following screenshot, everything is back to normal and the ping command will generate normal responses.
[image]

In summary, if ifconfig is used to the change the Ethernet interface's IP and mask,using it again to restore the initial link-local IP will result in network connection problems. Could anyone shed some light on this and offer a tip on how to restore the initial settings by using shell commands?

Comment: The address block 169.254.0.0/16 (everything beginning with 169.254) is link-local, meaning that it is only valid between two devices and not routed past the router.

Comment: Thanks for the commend. Why does the link-local address work initially and again after using Settings to set the link-local address?

Comment: Basically: You can't ping 192.168.1.163 (LAN device) from 169.254.0.125 (link-local) because the other device has no idea where to send the data to. On the other hand, there is no router capable of routing 192.168.1.0/24 for you because 192.168 is a private IP range, not reachable from anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help.  My post may be misleading somehow, but I do not know how to improve it.  Any tip will be appreciated. My point is the  link-local address 169.254.0.125 does work as long as it is set by Android Settings.  Yes, 192.168.1.163 can be pinged from 169.254.0.125.   I suspect this statement probably has confused you. I use the statement to state fact, not an opinion or speculation.  Please let me know how I can clarify this so it will be crystal clear to everyone.

Comment: Ah I understand, well that's certainly weird behavior, maybe it has multiple address (link-local and LAN) but nevertheless my rule of thumb is: if there is a link-local address, it's broken. Just configure an IP address on your network and save yourself from all the headache.